# Undefined method "store" when clearly it is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't understand why its doing this. I have the method defined in my `BusinessStore` model and then I scope back to it:

**business_store.rb**

```
class BusinessStore < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :website, :business_name, :address, :phone_number, :online_store
  belongs_to :business
  has_many :user_prices
  attr_accessor :business_name
  validates_presence_of :address, :unless => :website?
  validates_presence_of :business_name
  validates_inclusion_of :online_store, :in => [true, false]

  def store
    if self.online_store
      "#{business_name} - #{website}"
    else
      "#{business_name} - #{address}"
    end
  end

  def business_name
    business.name if business
  end

  def business_name=(name)
    self.business = Business.find_or_create_by_name(name) unless name.blank?
  end
end
```

**user_data/index.html.erb**

```
<% for user_price in @bought_today %>
   <%= number_to_currency(user_price.price) %>
   <%= truncate(user_price.product_name, :length => 62) %></td>
   <%= truncate(user_price.business_store.store, :length => 85) %></td> # here
   <%= user_price.purchase_date.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></td>
<% end %>
```

Then I go the page and get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `store' for nil:NilClass):
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Most likely `business_store` attribute of your `user_price` price is `nil`. You should check it and find out what's the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't that `#store` is undefined in `BusinessStore`, but that your call to `user_price.business_store` is returning `nil`, i.e. there is no association between the current `user_price` and a `BusinessStore`.

If you're sure that every `user_price` should belong to a `business_store`, you may need to check your model code for (what I assume is called) `UserPrice` and make sure you have your association set up there. In addition, you may need to make sure you're associatiating new `UserPrice` objects with a `BusinessStore`. This is commonly done using the [`.build` method](http://vinhboy.com/blog/2009/01/15/rails-new-vs-build/):

```
# In, for instance, UserPricesController#New
@user_price = @business_store.user_prices.build
```

This creates a new `UserPrice` model automatically associated with the `@business_store` object.

Comment: Thank you. I had some UserPrices assigned without a business store so it caused this, thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like your associations are not set correctly.
 Follow through @Alex's answer and report back if the error is still there.

Comment: wrbg wants the `store` to be a *method* of the model, it's not an attribute. `attr_accessor` defines getters and setters for an instance variable (named as the symbol you pass).

Comment: Oops, My mistake. Updated the answer now.